# Where do the square brackets come from?

Tags: arrays, string, go, formatting, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    a := []string{"abc", "edf"}
    log.Println(fmt.Sprint(a))
}
```

The above Go program will print the following output, with slice value inside the square brackets `"[]"`.

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 [abc edf]

And I want to know where in the source code that `[]` is added into the formatted string.

I checked the source code `src/fmt/print.go` file, but couldn't find the exact line of code that does this.

Could anyone provide a hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are printing the value of a slice. It is formatted / printed in [`print.go`](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go), unexported function `printReflectValue()`, currently line #980:

```
855 func (p *pp) printReflectValue(value reflect.Value, verb rune, depth int)
                                           (wasString bool) {

        // ...

947     case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
            // ...

979         } else {
980             p.buf.WriteByte('[')
981         }
```

and line #995:

```
994         } else {
995             p.buf.WriteByte(']')
996         }
```

Note that this is for "general" slices (like your `[]string`), byte slices are handled differently:

```
948         // Byte slices are special:
949         // - Handle []byte (== []uint8) with fmtBytes.
950         // - Handle []T, where T is a named byte type, with fmtBytes only
```

`[]byte` is printed in the unexported function `fmtBytes()`:

```
533 func (p *pp) fmtBytes(v []byte, verb rune, typ reflect.Type, depth int) {

            // ...

551         } else {
552             p.buf.WriteByte('[')
553         }

            // ...

566         } else {
567             p.buf.WriteByte(']')
568         }
```